# Powershell: Using -notcontains to compare arrays doesn't find non-matching values

Tags: arrays, powershell, contains

PS noob here (as will be obvious shortly) but trying hard to get better. In my exchange 2010 environment I import and export huge numbers of .pst files. Many will randomly fail to queue up and once they're not in the queue it's very tedious to sort through the source files to determine which ones need to be run again so I'm trying to write a script to do it.

first I run a dir on the list of pst files and fill a variable with the associated aliases of the accounts:

```
$vInputlist = dir $vPath -Filter *.pst |%{ get-mailbox -Identity $_.basename| select alias}
```

Then I fill a variable with the aliases of all the files/accounts that successfully queued:

```
$vBatch = foreach ($a in (Get-MailboxImportRequest -BatchName $vBatchname)) {get-mailbox $a.mailbox | select alias}
```

Then I compare the two arrays to see which files I need to queue up again:

```
foreach($should in $vInputlist){if ($vBatch -notcontains $should){Write-Host $should ""}}
```

It seems simple enough yet the values in the arrays never match, or not match, as the case may be. I've tried both -contains and -notcontains. I have put in a few sanity checks along the way like exporting the variables to the screen and/or to csv files and the data looks fine.

For instance, when $vInputlist is first filled I send it to the screen and it looks like this:

```
Alias
MapiEnableTester1.psiloveyou.com
MapiEnableTester2.psiloveyou.com
MapiEnableTester3.psiloveyou.com
MapiEnableTester4.psiloveyou.com
```

Yet that last line of code I displayed above (..write-host $should,"") will output this:
    @{Alias=MapiEnableTester1.psiloveyou.com}
    @{Alias=MapiEnableTester2.psiloveyou.com}
    @{Alias=MapiEnableTester3.psiloveyou.com}
    @{Alias=MapiEnableTester4.psiloveyou.com}

(those all display as a column, not sure why they won't show that way here)

I've tried declaring the arrays like this, $vInputlist = @()

I've tried instead of searching for the alias just cleaning .pst off off the $_.basename using .replace

I've searched on comparing arrays til I'm blue in the fingers  and I don't think my comparison is wrong, I believe that somehow no matter how I fill these variables I am corrupting or changing the data so that seemingly matching data simply doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Using `-contains` to compare objects aren't easy because the objects are never identical even though they have the same property with the same value. When you use `select alias` you get an array of pscustomobjects with the property `alias`.

Try using the `-expand` parameter in `select`, like

```
select -expand alias
```

Using `-expand` will extract the value of the alias property, and your lists will be two arrays of strings instead, which can be compared using `-contains` and `-notcontains`.

**UPDATE** I've added a sample to show you what happends with your code.

```
#I'm creating objects that are EQUAL to the ones you have in your code
#This will simulate the objects that get through the "$vbatch -notcontains $should" test
PS > $arr = @()
PS > $arr += New-Object psobject -Property @{ Alias="MapiEnableTester1.psiloveyou.com" }
PS > $arr += New-Object psobject -Property @{ Alias="MapiEnableTester2.psiloveyou.com" }
PS > $arr += New-Object psobject -Property @{ Alias="MapiEnableTester3.psiloveyou.com" }
PS > $arr | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }

@{Alias=MapiEnableTester1.psiloveyou.com}
@{Alias=MapiEnableTester2.psiloveyou.com}
@{Alias=MapiEnableTester3.psiloveyou.com}

#Now this is what you will get if you use "... | select -expand alias" instead of "... | select alias"
PS > $arrWithExpand = $arr | select -expand alias
PS > $arrWithExpand | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }

MapiEnableTester1.psiloveyou.com
MapiEnableTester2.psiloveyou.com
MapiEnableTester3.psiloveyou.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. When I tried it my "sanity check" csvs had "32" in all columns, so it seems that the property I got was length. You have given me another avenue to work with so I'd like to try a little longer on my own to get this worked out. I just didn't want you to think I didn't see or appreciate your help. Thank you very much and I'll update here when I have more.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you were trying to say here. You got `Length` instead of `Alias`? :S  I've updated the answer to include a sample where you can understand what's wrong with your code atm., and why `-expand` will help.